# Trying to switch to an iframe with no success

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium script (Python), that will find an element and write some text into it, the problem is that I cannot switch to the iframe where this element is.

Above this iframe there are 2 others that I have already switched to and identified/interacted with elements within.

This is the iframe info:

```
<iframe id="zzzzAIDGLKGG.VerticalContainerView.Iframe11420996026" ct="IF" lsdata="{&quot;0&quot;:&quot;100%&quot;,&quot;1&quot;:&quot;/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.portal.pagebuilder.IviewModeProxy?iview_id=pcd%3Aportal_content%2F.portal_pt%2F.role%2Fpt.telecom.order_entry%2F.order_entry%2F.acolhimento%2F.acolhimento_order_entry&amp;iview_mode=default&amp;ClientWindowID=WID1687259978810&quot;}" tabindex="0" ti="0" name="zzzzAIDGLKGG.VerticalContainerView.Iframe11420996026" forwarddragdropevents="false" src="/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.portal.pagebuilder.IviewModeProxy?iview_id=pcd%3Aportal_content%2Fportal_pt%2Frole%2Forder_entry%2F.order_entry%2Facolhimento%2Facolhimento_order_entry&amp;iview_mode=default&amp;ClientWindowID=WID1687259978810" border="no" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
```

This is my actual code:

```
driver.get('http://mysite.pt/irj/portal')
time.sleep(2)
#LOGIN
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'logonuidfield').send_keys('user')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'logonpassfield').send_keys('pass')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'uidPasswordLogon').click()
time.sleep(5)

wait = input("Press Enter to continue.0 ")

waitf = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
iframe = waitf.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "ivuFrm_page0ivu3")))  

wait = input("Press Enter to continue.1 ")
iframe = waitf.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "isolatedWorkArea")))    
wait = input("Press Enter to continue.2 ")

iframe = waitf.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "zzzzAIDGLKGG.VerticalContainerView.Iframe11420996026")))
```

this is where script breaks.

Tried this options:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'iframe[id="zzzzAIDGLKGG.VerticalContainerView.Iframe11420996026"]')
```

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="zzzzAIDGLKGG.VerticalContainerView.Iframe11420996026"]')
```

```
iframe = waitf.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'zzzzAIDGLKGG\\.VerticalContainerView\\.Iframe11420996026')))
```

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="zzzzAIDGLKGG.VerticalContainerView.Iframe11420996026"]')
```

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.portal.pagebuilder.IviewModeProxy?iview_id=pcd%3Aportal_content%2Fpt.portal_pt%2Fpt.telecom.role%2Fpt.telecom.order_entry%2Fpt.telecom.order_entry%2Fpt.telecom.acolhimento%2Fpt.acolhimento_order_entry&iview_mode=default&ClientWindowID=WID1687259978810']")
```

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='http://fullsitelink.pt/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.portal.pagebuilder.IviewModeProxy?iview_id=pcd%3Aportal_content%2Fpt.telecom.portal_pt%2Fpt.telecom.role%2Fpt.telecom.order_entry%2Fpt.telecom.order_entry%2Fpt.telecom.acolhimento%2Fpt.telecom.acolhimento_order_entry&iview_mode=default&ClientWindowID=WID1687259978810']")
```

Comment: Can you try changing to dynamic xpath as below.
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[contains(@id, 'VerticalContainerView')]')

Comment: Tried that and it finds the element, used a print trying to get the ID but still can't switch into the frame.
`iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'VerticalContainerView')]")
print(iframe)`

It gives me this output:
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8567fd98b62874d8be257afaa7b645f0", element="026DAFD27B67D2EDBE789BE6E3CEB640_element_93")>

Comment: Why you need to print the element. It is iframe. You want to do something after switching to frame right?. So there should be some link or textbox or button you would need to click or enter value. If you tried that then can you please paste the code along with html code.

Comment: Nevermind, i wasn't focused. Problem solved! thank you very much. Here is the code that solved the problem:
`iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'VerticalContainerView')]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'WD57').send_keys('TEST')`